# Java: Can you parse a file ON server?

Tags: java, client-server, download

I always understood that in order to read a file on the server you have to download it first ie:

```
  URL url = new URL(myUrl);
              connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              connection.connect();


              input = connection.getInputStream();
              output = new FileOutputStream(TEMP_FILE_PATH); 

             byte data[] = new byte[4096];
              long total = 0;
              int count;
              while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                  // allow canceling with back button
                  if (isCancelled()) {
                      input.close();
                      return null;
                  }
                   output.write(data, 0, count);
              }
```

Is my assumption incorrect? Can you read / parse  a file  without downloading it?

Comment: Technically, no.  Even if you don't physically download the file and save it locally, you will still be downloading the contents from the server to the client machine in memory so you can process it.  So I guess the answer depends on your definition of "download"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to parse a file ON server?

Yes, if your parser is running on the server. If your parser isn't running with direct access to the file then you have to fetch the file somehow to parse it.

Comment: hmmmm, are there any resources out there on this? Can mobile devices take advantage of this? Finally, what is best practice: downloading to physical device or using a "parser" on the server?

Comment: Resources on Java web technologies like Servlet and JSP? Re: mobile decives, it depends what do you intend to do with the data after it's been parsed? Re: best practice, depends where do you need your parsed data? What are you parsing?

Comment: I need to parse a very large file that is on a server and find some specific info within this file and display the results on a mobile device.

Comment: Then parse it on the server and send the relevant results to the mobile device. I suggest you read up on [multitier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

Comment: This would be pull notifications?

Comment: Only if it's in response to a mobile device request. As in the client says I want to "pull" data. It could also be used with push notification.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to parse a file ON server?

Definitely **YES** you can.

Based on your code snippet, you seem to want to read and parse a file content from a remote server or http request.

I have an application in which user can preview a file from a remote file server.

If you can access a file using "myUrl" directly, you can also read and parse the file in java.

Please try to use the code snippet below.

You may need to include **org.apache.http.client.HttpClient** library.

**HTTP GET Example**

```
String myUrl = "http://enter.the.url.you.want";
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("TEMP_FILE_PATH");

// Define Header information if you want to have.
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("range", "bytes=0-51199");

// org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(myUrl);

if(headers != null){
    Iterator<String> iter = headers.keySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        get.addHeader(key, headers.get(key));
    }
}

HttpResponse res = client.execute(get);
InputStream input = res.getEntity().getContent();

int count = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[4096];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    sb.append(new String(data, 0, count, "UTF-8"));
    // Here is the place you can read a file.
    output.write(data);
}

input.close();
output.close();
```

**HTTP POST Example**

```
String myUrl = "http://enter.the.url.you.want";
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("TEMP_FILE_PATH");

// Define parameters if you want to have.
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "some-value"));

// Define Header information if you want to have.
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put("range", "bytes=0-51199");

// org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(myUrl);
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

if(headers != null){
    Iterator<String> iter = headers.keySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        post.addHeader(key, headers.get(key));
    }
}

HttpResponse res = client.execute(post);
InputStream input = res.getEntity().getContent();

int count = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[4096];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    sb.append(new String(data, 0, count, "UTF-8"));
    // Here is the place you can read a file.
    output.write(data);
}

input.close();
output.close();
```